# Using statement won't work - VS 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a c# MVC project, and I'm trying to use the DbContext class, which is supposedly derived from the System.Data.Entity.DbContext class.  However, when I add the using statement:

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

"Entity" gets the red underline and I get the error saying the namespace 'Entity' doesn't exist in the namespace 'System.Data.'  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the Solution-Explorer, right-click your project, select Manage Packages, Add EF 5.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.  If you want to make that an answer, I'd be happy to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a library. The `using <namespace>;` statement is only about naming things, it does not give access to assemblies.

You can only access a library (assembly) that is in the references list of the project. Right-click and use Add-Reference to add an additional library.

For all libraries that have their own release cycles, the preferred way to add (and update/remove) them is through the NuGet package manager.

> In the Solution-Explorer, right-click your project, select Manage Packages, Add Entity Framework 5.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to add reference to System.Data.Entity.dll

Comment: FYI - you can google the class you want and Microsoft's page will show you the required dll in the "Assembly:" section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: But much better to use NuGet.